# method to remove object if condition

Tags: java

```
public void removeThem(int nrF){
    if(index == 0){
        System.out.println("array is empty!");
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        String e = books[i].getName();
        if(e.length() > 12 && e.split(" ").length > nrF){
            for(int j = i; j < index - 1; j++){
                books[j] = books[j + 1];
            }
            books[--index] = null;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

nrF is the number of a sentence's words.I dont understand why  books[j] is equal to books[j+1]?

Comment: It is nor *equals* it assigns `books[j + 1]` value to `books[j]`. By the way, Where do you define `index`?

Comment: *"I dont understand why books[j] is equal to books[j+1]?"* - Because you literally told it to do that?: `books[j] = books[j + 1];`  It's not really clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Isaac, welcome to SE! Like vahdet, I was wondering where these other (presumably global) variables came from. As he stated, the "=" operator means give [variable on left] val from [variable on right]. It is not a mathematical statement.

Comment: index is defined in
 public void addBook(Book b){
int index = 0;
  books[index++] =b;
 }

Comment: i have to learn it so i didnt do it myself , its supposed to be a remove method.

Comment: @IsaacTeel: *"index is defined in public void addBook"* - That defines a variable local to the `addBook` method, which isn't relevant here.  This is a different method with a different variable, which *isn't* defined in this method and therefore must exist in a higher scope.

Comment: @IsaacTeel: Have to learn *what*?  Didn't do *what* yourself?  It's still not at all clear what you're asking here.  When you step through this code in a debugger, what specific operation is failing in some way?  How is it failing?

Comment: @IsaacTeel especially if you have to learn [how to do] it, you should attempt to do it yourself. did you write this code? did you find it somewhere?

Comment: Read [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) from the beginning.  It'll be much easier than trying to learn fundamental Java concepts from SO.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are not the author of this method.

A single `=` is not an equality check in Java, it is an assignment operator.

```
books[j] = books[j + 1];
```

means "books[j] has now the value of books[j+1]".

Doing this on every subsequent element of the array will effectively remove the specified element of said array.

Here's an [image: amazing diagram] : you simply "compress" the array.